# Memory allocation of a float array in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory, malloc

I would like to create a `float` array of 9 elements. Thus I made use of `malloc` primitve function to do so :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void main(void){
  float* y;
  printf("sizeof(float)=%ld\n",sizeof(float));
  y = malloc (10*sizeof(float));
  printf("sizeof(y)=%ld\n", sizeof(y));
  float *x;
  x = (float *) malloc(9*sizeof(float));
  printf("sizeof(x)=%ld\n", sizeof(x));

}
```

The output is the following:

```
sizeof(float)=4
sizeof(y)=8
sizeof(x)=8
```

Therefore I am wondering why both `sizeof(y)` and `sizeof(x)` return 8. Shouldń't they return `10*sizeof(float)=10*4=40` and `9*sizeof(float)=9*4=36` respectively? Could someone please clarify to me why am I getting 8 instead for both arrays?

Answer (score 2):

`x` and `y` are not declared as arrays.  They are pointers to memory locations.  Depending on the system, the pointers could be 8 bytes.  That's what you're seeing.

If you were to declare an array `int z[10]`, and did `sizeof(z)`, you'd get `10*sizeof(int)`.